"DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1" message does not go away in python selenium
I know this question is a duplicate. However, no matter how much I write, the following phrase will not disappear.

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:62784/devtools/browser/9f06f86e-f98b-4896-9f35-8c5c73317c7a

There is a reason why the above phrase should be deleted. You need to import usd-to-krw, kospi, and nasdaq indices from external sources and print them to the console. And I copy that console and use it. But the above correctly linked statement is stuck in the middle of my entire text. I don't want the above text to be printed because it's inconvenient to erase it every time.
Here is the full code I used:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

def get_usd_to_krw_exchange_rate():

    service = Service(
        executable_path = ChromeDriverManager().install(),
        log_path=os.devnull
    )
    
    options = Options()
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
    options.add_argument('--disable-logging')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        service = service,
        options = options
    )
    
    driver.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=usd+to+krw')
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    rate = soup.select_one('#knowledge-currency__updatable-data-column > div.b1hJbf > div.dDoNo.ikb4Bb.gsrt > span.DFlfde.SwHCTb').get_text()
    print(rate)

get_usd_to_krw_exchange_rate()

Please let me know what more I should do or what I'm doing wrong.

You could just filter it out when you run the code, e.g. with python3 myScript.py | grep -v DevTools, or on Windows python3 myScript.py | findstr /v DevTools
